# Set width on div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to give the div a width of 495px. Why is it not working?

I will use a link instead of a button and the textbox will be the "button".

```css
.text_box {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 62px;
  margin-bottom: 200px;
}

.button {
  border: 2px solid #04fbc7;
  padding-top: 33px;
  padding-bottom: 35px;
  padding-left: 120px;
  padding-right: 120px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 18px;
  letter-spacing: 0.100em;
}

.button:hover {
  color: white;
  background: #05fbc7;
}
```

```html
<div class="text_box">
  <a href="#" class="button">Show more</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Because you didn't define a width of 495px anywhere in your example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding, try something like that:

```
.text_box {
  text-align: center;
  width: 495px;
  margin: 0 auto;}
```

and

```
.button {
  border: 2px solid #04fbc7;
  padding-top: 33px;
  padding-bottom: 35px;
  padding-left: 120px;
  padding-right: 120px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 18px;
  letter-spacing: 0.100em;
  display: block;}
```

Note that in the `.button` is like **display: block;** 
because by default the ancor tag `<a />` is displayed inline

otherwise, the ancor tag `<a />` can not fill the width in a DIV

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I also changed the name on the .button.

Answer (score 1):

The more professional way to do this would be to edit the css so that you have. By editing the css this will help keep your code and styling more consistent while you develop.

```
.text_box {
  width: 495px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 62px;
  margin-bottom: 200px;
}
```